# The riddle of no sense

Tags: riddle, cipher, language, cryptic-clues

Rx wnz gur nfjnq lreruxn bs rxngv mhev onpxn, n ormxevy atunng, ibynag gnnf furamuv muv n boynpv m uvzzry vx tvir anfxvtb rg yhun bs qrhyv ra zbfgfniyrrov qnf flnagb Znar, zraz xbqnlnxr nxjnv b km xnnena enh onang, bt an frxnyv ne zvb gnawb v nz rcveru gbj tbattv.

What am I?
**Hint:**

> (Dirty Old Food, 7th prime)

Comment: You might want to look at [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do).  And as per my last comment, I strongly encourage you to *stop* posting puzzles, for at least a day.  Maybe plan a bigger, more polished puzzle, perhaps even one that incorporates several different smaller puzzles.

Comment: I will and P.S. I've been planning this one for almost a week now and it DOES incorperate lots of different puzzles.

Comment: Based on the tag, I imagine this is in a foreign language, which makes it a lot harder to solve based on common letter patterns.....

Comment: I look forward to seeing the solution, then, when it is solved.  You might want to look through some of the responses to the question I linked above, and see if there are ways you can flesh out your puzzle a bit (maybe provide some hidden hints in flavourtext, or some other indication of how you expect it to be solved).  Happy puzzling!

Comment: Puzzlers, beware: the hint can be misleading in that the list of primes here includes 1 as a prime.

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are:

> Smoke

Using @rhsquared partial answer, I was able to figure out translations to enough of the words until I recognized:

> That I had heard this riddle before. The full riddle goes: I am the black child of a white father, a wingless bird, flying even to the
>  clouds of heaven. I give birth to tears of mourning in pupils that
>  meet me, even though there is no cause for grief, and at once on my
>  birth I am dissolved into air. What am I?

Comment: *Hello!* Welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (Puzzling.SE)**! Great answer! Even though you have heard this riddle before, you formatted your answer very well. Since you are new to the Stack Exchange community, however, especially this site, I strongly recommend you visit the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help). In particular, since you have not asked any questions/puzzles (yet!), I suggest heading to the *Asking* section (e.g. [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). *Happy Puzzling!* :D

Comment: @chris well done

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

The hint:

> Considering that 1 is assumed to be prime, means rot 13 - old food and the 7th prime counting one.

The puzzle

> So first step - rot13 the supplied text which gives the following:
> Ek jam the aswad yerehka of ekati zuri backa, a bezkril nghaat, volant taas shenzhi zhi a oblaci z himmel ik give naskigo et luha of deuli en mostsavleebi das syanto Mane, menm kodayake akwai o xz kaaran rau banat, og na sekali ar mio tanjo i am epireh tow gonggi.
>  What attracted my attention is were the words "oblaci z himmel". Now "oblaci" means clouds in Bulgarian and himmel is heaven in German.
>  So I started to play with google translate and it seems that we have lots of different languages

Comment: What do you make of the hint though? 7th prime is 17, I thought it might be ROT17

Comment: Oh dear, context-free piecemeal translation. `:(`

Comment: 7 th prime (including 1)

Comment: @rhsquared well done

Comment: 1 isn't prime though...

Comment: @mmking that has been debateable for years - please just don't go off-topic and work with me.

Comment: @WilliamPennanti I can't find any reliable source that says that 1 is prime. If you have one, I'd honeslty like to see it. If not, then it's definitly not debatable.

Comment: @WilliamPennanti just very quickly, adding to what **LioraHaydont** said, the debate is over and has officially settled with the conclusion that $1$ is **not** a prime number, nor composite either. This is clearly asserted in the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (FTA)](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/fundamental-theorem-arithmetic.html), and for good reason, too (for which a more advanced explanation can be found [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/fundamental-theorem-of-arithmetic/)). But yeah, you are right in saying to not become off-topic :)

Comment: I have an objection to the "don't go off topic" comment. Claiming something to be true that the majority of the world does not consider to be true, and in particular, **using it as a hint in a cipher puzzle**, makes it near impossible to solve the puzzle.

Comment: @user477343 thanks. I thought the debate was ongoing